# How to call Monotonic Spline function

Tags: javascript

Let me preface this with, I'm not a math whiz by any means. I am interested in fitting a curve like the Monotonic Spline function to my data.

I am trying to get this Javascript version of a Monotonic Spline function to work and can't figure out how to call the function properly. Specifically, the beginning of the code starts like this (I've never seen a function named in this manner before):

```
var CubicSpline, MonotonicCubicSpline;
MonotonicCubicSpline = function() {
  function MonotonicCubicSpline(x, y) {
```

To me, the same function is defined in two different scopes. The first doesn't take any parameters and the second one does. How do you get around this?

I started with just supplying the points I wanted to fit:

```
MonotonicCubicSpline([0,5,10,15,20,25], [0,6,2,6,7,10])
```

but that portion of the function doesn't return anything, it seems as if I need to call the function with the same name above that. If you want to test this out, here's a jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/SszKr/7/

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Credit for the function goes to:
http://blog.mackerron.com/2011/01/01/javascript-cubic-splines/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *MonotonicCubicSpline* function declaration, we can see that there is an *interpolate* function added to the prototype and that the constructor function returns nothing.

So you have to declare a new *MonotonicCubicSpline* then use its *interpolate* function.

Example:

```
var mySpline = new MonotonicCubicSpline([0,5,10,15,20,25], [0,6,2,6,7,10]);
console.log(mySpline.interpolate(3));
```

I'm not sure but I suppose that the *interpolate* function argument is the abscissa.

Comment: Thanks so much @Zapshu! I wish I could give this a plus 2!